# data being reset when returns to main function pointers c/linux

Tags: c, pointers

still not fixed new code added

im using c in linux for my course and im having problems with pointers as im managing to store the data in the pointer but when it returns to the main function its been reset. im mystified as its acting like a regular variable

can anyone help me keep the data after the function is complete

ive tried the solution below but new i get segmentation errors

```
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

//defines
#define BUFFSIZE 1000000
#define PROCS 2

//prototypes
void read_file(char *filename,  char** buffer);

/* The name of this program. */
const char* program_name;


int main (int argc, char* argv[]){
//records keystroke
    int next_option;
//records values
    int print_chars = 0, print_words = 0, print_lines = 0;
    char* fileName = "/usr/share/dict/words";
    char* buffer;
    char** ptb = &buffer;
    int check;
/* designates options
     -h --help Display this usage information. 
     -n --num Display my student number. 
     -c --chars Print number of characters in FILENAME. 
     -w --words Print number of words in FILENAME. 
     -l --lines Print number of lines in FILENAME. 
     -f --file FILENAME Read from file. 
*/
    const char* const short_options = "f:";
    const struct option long_options[] = {
        { "file", 1, NULL, 'f' },
        { NULL, 0, NULL, 0 }};
//calls functions when the keys are pressed
    do {
        next_option = getopt_long (argc, argv, short_options,
        long_options, NULL);
        switch (next_option){
            case 'f': /* -f or --file */
                fileName = optarg;
                read_file (fileName, ptb);
                printf("%s\nreturned\n", buffer);   
                check = 1;          
                break;
            case '?': /* The user specified an invalid option. */
                check = 1;
            case -1: /* Done with options. */
                if(!check){
                    if(!buffer[0]){
                        read_file (fileName, ptb);
                    }
                    printf("No command was entered so default :\n");
                }
                break;
            default: /* Something else: unexpected. */
                abort ();
        }
    }while (next_option != -1);
}
void read_file (char *file, char** buffer){
    FILE    *fp = fopen(file, "r"); //file that is being read
    long    numbytes;
    int len = 0;

//quit if file doesn't exist
    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("File not found at: %s\n", file);
        return;
    } 

    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END); //goes to end of file
    numbytes = ftell(fp);   // Get the number of bytes
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);    //goes to beginning of file
    numbytes = numbytes + sizeof(char);
    *buffer = (char*)calloc(numbytes, sizeof(char));//allocates memory
    len = fread(*buffer, sizeof(char), numbytes, fp);// copy all the text into the buffer

    if(len == 0){
        printf("Write to memory error\n");
        return;
    }
        *buffer[++len] = '\0';//put end terminater in
    fclose(fp);         
    printf("%s\n", *buffer);

    printf("File location :%s\n", file);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Could you show us what you have for `main()` and `read_file()`?

Comment: `gdb` is your friend.

Comment: `buffer = (char*)calloc(BUFFSIZE, sizeof(char));` don't need.

Answer (score 0):

Your memory management is off. You create buffer[BUFFSIZE] in main and pass a pointer to that area to your function, but in your function you allocate another memory area using calloc where you read the file into, but no pointer to that area is ever returned to main.
You should get rid of your buffer variable in main and let readFile return the pointer you receive from calloc. E.g. you could change your function prototype to:

```
 void read_file (char *file, char** buffer);
```

And when you use calloc you do

```
 *buffer = calloc(...);
```

(following uses of buffer will need appropriate dereferencing.

Furthermore, I think you access invalid memory. You check how many bytes are in the file and allocate that much memory and then read all those bytes. But eventually you do:

```
 buffer[++len] = '\0';
```

If I'm not mistaken that accesses a byte beyond the allocated memory area.

Comment: Three things:
1. gdb is your friend. You should compile your program with debug info and run it in gdb and it tells you where it crashes
2. *buffer[foo] apparently needs parentheses, change it to (*buffer)[foo]
3. As mentioned in my answer above, you don't allocate enough memory in your calloc call. Make it 'numbytes + 1' to have space for the '\0'